# I am having one EditText for which i have set onClickListener and opening material Calendar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-calendar

I am having one EditText for which i have set onClickListener and opening material Calendar. Problem is that when i am running application in emulator its working but when i am running in mobile device its stop on clicking on edit text and showing error 
**Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe + android**

```
  from_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int Year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int Day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            flage_from=true;
            flage_to=false;
            datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(MainActivity.this, Year, Month, Day);
            datePickerDialog.setThemeDark(false);


            datePickerDialog.showYearPickerFirst(false);

            datePickerDialog.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#215f8b"));

           // datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");

            datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerDialog");

        }
    });
```

@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int Year, int Month, int Day)
    {

```
    String date = Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year;
        if(flage_from){
            from_date.setText(date);
        }else {
            to_date.setText(date);

        }
}
```

Comment: What you have done so far? Show your efforts.

Comment: Nothing @AndyDeveloper

Comment: see my post i hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some idea from this.This is not exactly what you want but it is similar to your question.

[Link 1](https://github.com/bilthon/Android-Speedometer)

[Link 2](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4169)